Root separation for polynomials of bounded height
Consider integer polynomials $p$ of degree $\leq d$ and height $\leq H$, irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. The separation $\text{sep}(p)$ of $p$ is defined as the minimum absolute difference between any two roots of $p$. From the classical result of Mahler on root separation we have $$\text{sep}(p) > \sqrt{3} (d+1)^{-(2d+1)/2}H^{-d+1},$$ so that roughly we have $\ln (\text{sep}(p)^{-1}) = O(d\ln d + d\ln H)$. Other bounds on separation, such as those by Rump or Bugeaud lead to the same lower bound of $O(d\ln d + d\ln H)$. Is it possible to get rid of the $d\ln d$ term? More formally, does there exist a constant $C > 0$ such that $\text{sep}(p) > (2H)^{-Cd}$? Note the factor of $2$ to deal with the case where $H = 1$.
The available literature on root separation seems mainly focused on improving the exponent of $H$ in the separation bound, which only worsens the dependency on $d$. I have not been able to find any literature on improving the bound when $H \ll d$.
It could of course be the case that it is impossible to improve the dependency on $d$. Then there should be a sequence of polynomials with fixed $H$, or at least $H \ll d$, whose root separation decreases like $d^{-d}$. The best family of polynomials I have found is due to Mignotte:
$$
p_d(X) = X^{d} - 2(2X-1)^2
$$
of height $8$, whose separation decreases like $2^{-d/2}$. Ideas such as modifying the polynomial to $X^d - 2f_d(X)^2$ where $f_d(X)$ has a root decreasing like $d^{-1}$ have been fruitless as the height of $f_d$ would need to increase like $d$, since the minimal non-zero root of an integer polynomial of height $H$ has absolute value at least $(1+H)^{-1}$.
